# What could be a decent workflow to a user registration application to store password?

Tags: database, authentication, user-controls, passwords, password-protection

I am developing an application (web\mobile). The user have to register the account using a form on the application (it contains some data as **username** and **password**).

These data have to be stored in a database table, these data travel on Internet so I think that it is not a good idea that the password is in clear.

I think that  the client have to encrypt the password in some ways and that this crypted password have to be stored in the DB.

What could be a decent workflow for this task?

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do this is to send the password as clear text via a HTTPS connection. HTTPS is a must when anything confidential is sent through internet, not only for passwords.

On the server, calculate a hash. There are many algorithms for this, some more secure than others. A hash function works only for one direction: the password cannot be derived from the hash. Store that hash to the database instead of the password. When a User logs in, calculate a hash from that password, and compare it to the hash stored to the database.